# Using a string to write to an array

Tags: java, arrays, string

Attempting to tidy up code, originally I was using this method of writing to arrays, which is ridiculously long when I have to repeat it 20 times

```
        if (ant.getAntNumber() == 3)
        {
            numbers3.add(ant.getCol());
            numbers3y.add(ant.getRow());
        }

        if (ant.getAntNumber() == 4)
        {
            numbers4.add(ant.getCol());
            numbers4y.add(ant.getRow());
        }
```

I attempted to use a for loop to do it but I cant figure out how to add to the array using the string value, because it thinks its a string rather than trying to use the array

```
for (int j = 0; j<maxAnts; j++)
        {
            String str = "numbers" + j;
            String str2 = "numbers" + j + "y";
            //this part doesnt work
            str.add(ant.getCol());

        }
```

Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: Your `number3`, `number4`, ..., `numberN` should belong to an array, that's it.

Comment: Array of string is declared as String[] str = new String()[SIZE];

Comment: talking abt array or collection ?

Comment: String had no method `add(...)` you should use a cotainer to add several strings in it. (Array or Collection)

Comment: I'm confused about what you are trying to do. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha: no, that's not how you create an array.

Comment: @JBNizet my bad.. Array of string is declared as String[] str = new String[SIZE]. Is this alright ?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha It's OK now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you cannot use the value of a `String` object to reference an actual variable name.  Java will think you're attempting to to call `add` on the `String` object, which doesn't exist and gives you the compiler error you're seeing.

To avoid the repetition, you need to add your `List`s to two master lists that you can index.

In your question, you mention arrays, but you call `add`, so I'm assuming that you're really referring to `List`s of some sort.

```
List<List<Integer>> numbers = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(20);
List<List<Integer>> numbersy = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(20);
// Add 20 ArrayList<Integer>s to each of the above lists in a loop here.
```

Then you can bounds-check `ant.getAntNumber()` and use it as an index into your master lists.

```
int antNumber = ant.getAntNumber();
// Make sure it's within range here.

numbers.get(antNumber).add(ant.getCol());
numbersy.get(antNumber).add(ant.getRow());
```

Comment: How would I then get this data back? Currently using this from my old version

    for (int i = 0; i<numbers.size(); i++)
   {
    int x = numbers.get(i);
    int y = numbersy.get(i);
    Ant.world[x][y].increasePheromone(2);
   }

This is to get the route back which the ant has taken, and then increase the pheromone value on all of the cells which the ant has traversed, thanks

Comment: Like populating the lists, call `get` on your master lists to get the proper lists for each ant, then iterate over both of those lists to get your `x` and `y` values back out.

Comment: the solution you provided is giving me an index out of bounds exception, as it says the size of it is always 0, is this because I'm trying to get it before theres anything stored in it?

Comment: Yes.  Add empty lists where I commented, "Add 20 ArrayList<Integer>s".

Comment: sorry to be so simple but you have confused me :(

Comment: Right now, you only have 2 empty master lists.  Each of your lists needs 20 empty lists to add to, one for each of the 20 cases you implied that you have.  Add 20 empty lists to each of your master lists, so that when you call `getCol()` and `getRow()`, you have a list to which to add them.

Comment: Even after creating ArrayList<Integer> numbers0 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 ArrayList<Integer> numbers1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); etc, I'm still getting the same error

Comment: I managed to make it work I was just being stupid, thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
Ant[] aAnt = new Ant[20];

//Fill the ant-array

int[] aColumns = new int[aAnt.length];
int[] aRows = new int[aAnt.length];

for(int i = 0; i < aAnt.length; i++)  {
   aColumns[i] = aAnt[i].getCol();
   aRows[i] = aAnt[i].getRow();
}
```

or with lists:

```
List<Integer> columnList = new List<Integer>(aAnt.length);
List<Integer> rowList = new List<Integer>(aAnt.length);

for(Ant ant : aAnt)  {
   columnList.add(ant.getCol());
   rowList.add(ant.getRow());
}
```

or with a col/row object:

```
class Coordinate  {
   public final int yCol;
   public final int xRow;
   public Coordinate(int y_col, int x_row)  {
      yCol = y_col;
      xRow = x_row;
   }
}

//use it with

List<Coordinate> coordinateList = new List<Coordinate>(aAnt.length);
for(Ant ant : aAnt)  {
   coordinateList.add(ant.getCol(), ant.getRow());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A straight-forward port of your code would be to use two `Map<Integer, Integer>` which store X and Y coordinates. From your code it seems like ant numbers are unique, i.e., we only have to store a single X and Y value per ant number. If you need to store multiple values per ant number, use a `List<Integer>` as value type of the `Map` instead.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> numbersX = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
Map<Integer, Integer> numbersY = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

for(Ant ant : ants) {
    int number = ant.getAntNumber();        
    numbersX.put(number, ant.getCol());
    numbersY.put(number, ant.getRow());
}
```